# WSO2 Identitiy Server Password change failing with "Can not access the directory service for user"

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am attempting to setup both the Password Change and Password Reset features.

When I attempt to change my test accounts password I see this message

```
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.password.mgt.ChangePasswordServlet} -  Change Password Failed
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.common.UserAdminException: Can not access the directory service for user : <my test account>
```

I am using Active Directory, I am using an LDAPS connection, the connecting user does have permission to change the password.

I can login to federated services using the test account.

Thanks,
...pat

This is Ellucian's distribution 2.0.2 of WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to alter my Referral setting from 'ignore' to 'follow'.  Once I made that change both Password Change and Password Reset features started to work.

...pat

Answer (score 0):

If the AD is the PRIMARY userstore, then in user-mgt.xml file, you need to add credentials of a administrative level user account of AD.

```
        <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
```

If the AD is a secondary userstore, then in the particular userstore's configuration, you need to do the same as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, however my connecting user already is a privileged user.